# Initialize structure with macro

Tags: c, gcc

I'm looking for a way to initialize structure using macro. 
I want to initialize it according to this way.

```
struct st_test {
  int first;
  int second;
};

STRUCT_INIT (name_of_var) = {.first = 1, .second = 2};
```

How can i do that?

I found answer here it is

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

#define SEC_INIT_FN(type, var,...)              \
    __VA_ARGS__ struct _SIF_ {                  \
        type (* fn) (int i);                    \
    } var;                                      \
static void __sec_init_fn_reg_##var (void)      \
    __attribute__((__constructor__)) ;          \
static void __sec_init_fn_reg_##var (void)      \
{                                               \
    var.fn(10);                                 \
}                                               \
__VA_ARGS__ struct _SIF_ var

void test_fn (int i) {
    printf("Test Function \n");
    printf("%d \n", i);
}

SEC_INIT_FN (void, T) = {.fn = test_fn };

int 
main(void)
{
    printf ("Main Function\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Have good time :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see the point with the syntax you just gave, but nevertheless here is a macro that should do something similar.

```
#define MY_STRUCT_INIT(var, fst, snd) struct st_test (var) = {.first=(fst),.second=(snd)}
```

and use it like so

```
MY_STRUCT_INIT(pair, 10, 98);
```

Answer (score -1):

does not make too much sense but ... (tested with gcc)

```
#define STRUCT_INIT(s,f1,f2,v1,v2)   struct st_test s = {.f1 = (v1), .f2 = (v2)}

struct st_test {
  int first;
  int second;
};

STRUCT_INIT(name_of_var,first,second,1,2);
```